# Error on Integrating Admob unity 3d games for WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, admob

Hi Everyone i am integrating `Admob` in my `Unity 3d Games` for `WP8`. I follow the developers guide to integrate `Admob SDK WP8` but when i tried to Ad "adview" both by dragging and using code line for it. I received Error!!!. I have tried tweaking and searching the web a lot and tried other forums but not got a appropriate suggestion to fix this issue.

I am beginner, your help can save my hours. Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the propreties of your GoogleAds.dll file and check if on the bottom of the General page it is "locked" and unlock it. On your visual studio project under reference, right click->add reference, and add it again